# Difference between a given number and 13 displays -13 for every number I enter

Tags: javascript

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>xxxxxxxxxxx</title>
</head>
<input id="nr1" type="text"></br>
<input id="calc" type="button" onClick="calc();return false;" value="calc">
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
const nr1 = document.getElementById("nr1").value;
const nr2 = 13;
const button = document.getElementById("calc");
function calc() {
   if(nr1 - nr2 >= 13){
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (nr1-nr2)*2;
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = nr1-nr2;
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does it display -13 for every number I enter?
I think I'm missing something, but I just can't get what's happening.

Comment: Put `const nr1 ...` into the function

Comment: yes, inside the function ! and maybe casting it explicitly to an integer would make code easier to read/understand

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of user input is stored at DOM load which is empty at that point. In other words, cache the input, not its `value`. The input must be converted to a number to perform arithmetic.

```js
const 
nr2 = 13,
nr1 = document.getElementById("nr1"),
button = document.getElementById("calc");

function calc() {

  let n1 = Number( nr1.value ); // convert to number. See browser support

  if(n1 - nr2 >= 13) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (n1-nr2)*2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n1-nr2;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="nr1" type="text"></br>
<input id="calc" type="button" onClick="calc();return false;" value="calc">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful!